# In python, find minimum subject to a constraint?

Tags: python, min

How do I find the index idx, such that dist[idx] is minimum, but only amongst those whose visited[idx] is false ? The context is for an implementation of Dijkstra's algorithm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
min((idx for idx in indexes if not visited[idx]), key=lambda idx: dist[idx])
```